# Can't pass the shipping address step on checkout with bootstrap theme

Tags: sylius

On a fresh sylius standard app created using composer create and updated to sylius 1.7.5 I followed the docs to install official bootsrap theme, the assets has been build successfully but when I test the checkout I can't pass the shipping address.
The form keep displaying errors on the required fields although being filled in with data

I checked the profiler and chrome network tab the form data was sent:

```
_method: PUT
sylius_checkout_address[customer][email]: test@test.com
_csrf_shop_security_token: G7YG5u59Lp0i4wysjq3REd-2U1RH5A3xYRVzpT97p_U
sylius_checkout_address[shippingAddress][firstName]: test
sylius_checkout_address[shippingAddress][lastName]: test
sylius_checkout_address[shippingAddress][company]: test
sylius_checkout_address[shippingAddress][street]: test 23
sylius_checkout_address[shippingAddress][countryCode]: FR
sylius_checkout_address[shippingAddress][provinceName]: ttyty
sylius_checkout_address[shippingAddress][city]: paris
sylius_checkout_address[shippingAddress][postcode]: 27003
sylius_checkout_address[shippingAddress][phoneNumber]: 0909009990
sylius_checkout_address[billingAddress][firstName]: 
sylius_checkout_address[billingAddress][lastName]: 
sylius_checkout_address[billingAddress][company]: 
sylius_checkout_address[billingAddress][street]: 
sylius_checkout_address[billingAddress][countryCode]: 
sylius_checkout_address[billingAddress][city]: 
sylius_checkout_address[billingAddress][postcode]: 
sylius_checkout_address[billingAddress][phoneNumber]: 
sylius_checkout_address[_token]: ffypC0OV8fB34hIoiHD75PEQDR5CsudpFsoUYI_xrZU
```

[image: request sent data on profiler]

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Note: The form works without the theme

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly by reading the section **Billing and shipping addresses have been switched with one another** in [the upgrade guide to sylius 1.7 version](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/UPGRADE-1.7.md#billing-and-shipping-addresses-have-been-switched-with-one-another) and by comparing the master branch code and the 0.1.1 release I found out that I don't have the same code.
So the solution was to change the minimum stability to dev and set the sylius/bootstrap-theme version to dev master

I'll keep my config like that till a new version with latest code is released.